# How to pass a dict as kwargs to a templatetag in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to pass a dictionary of parameters as kwargs to a templatetag.

Normally, we would write:

```
{% my_templatetag x=1 y=2 %}
```

What if we have these arguments as a dict provided by a view?

```
context['parameters'] = { 'x' : 1, 'y' : 2 }
```

Unfortunately, the following code does not work:

```
{% my_templatetag **parameters %}
```

Comment: Maybe it's not possible? Not strictly relevant, but [related](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/templates.html#accessing-method-calls): "Because Django intentionally limits the amount of logic processing available in the template language, it is not possible to pass arguments to method calls accessed from within templates. Data should be calculated in views, then passed to templates for display."

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#passing-template-variables-to-the-tag . So the idea is to *resolve* a variable present in the template's context from within the template tag rather than *directly* passing it to the tag.